What's your opinion
I want to create a spl coin with a transaction tax and from the youtube vids I've seen it says that I can easily create one on fluxbeam. I just wanted to know from the more knowledgeable and experienced ppl here if Fluxbeam is safe or would it be better to create one from scratch?

If you are looking for ease of use and don't require much customization, and you're comfortable trusting the platform’s security, Fluxbeam could be a good choice.
If you need full control and customization, or if security is a top concern, then creating the token from scratch might be better. However, you’ll need to make sure you understand the complexities and security aspects of token creation on Solana.
